# NLog file logging from Visual Studio but not when I build and install the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nsis, nlog

I am integrating Nlog on an existing desktop application, to write logs to a shared folder. When running the application from Visual Studio, it writes files fine, both log file and internalLog file for debugging. But when I make a build and install it on the same machine it no longer writes the files.

Edit:
Language c#, and build using NSIS to create installers.
Nlog.config is in the root folder of the project, and configuration (partial)

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="file-location"
            archiveFileName="archive-location"
            enableFileDelete="false" ...
```

Comment: Can you add more details of the language/platform, and maybe add the relevant code fragments?

Comment: @m69, I added some edits. let me know if you need more info

Comment: WHen you say shared folder do you mean an UNC path or a local folder that is shared? Have you tried repointng logdir to `%TEMP%`?

Comment: Found the issue and solution; config file was getting omitted build